# Thumbnail creation as preview for XML file

Tags: java, xml

How to create thumbnail for an XML document using Java?

I need to create a thumbnail for an XML file. I preferred to convert that XML to image but I got failed in it. The thumbnail should be a preview of the XML content.

I tried this code :

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("sample");
Thumbnails.of("file-path").size(100,100).toOutputStream(os);
```

Above is my code to convert image to thumbnail but I need to create thumbnail for an XML. Still i haven't find the code to convert XML to image.

Comment: What code have you tried and where exactly is it failing?

Comment: Thumbnail is for an Image, XML is Text ... You need some reply, but we need to understand your question sorry ...

Comment: FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("sample");
        Thumbnails.of(//file_path)
        .size(100,100)
        .toOutputStream(os);        above is my code to convert image to thumbnail but i need to create thumbnail for an xml.Still i haven't find the code to convert xml to image.

Comment: How does the XML correspond to an image?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen OP is wanting something like this kind of preview : http://bostonpeng.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/dolphin-pdf-thumbnails.png

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie so a tiny version of the raw XML text?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's how I understand it, I've also wanted something like that when I upload files in my projects manager (web). In KDE you already have something like this, for preview PDF, txt, XML and of course thumbnail of images.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this in two steps :

**Read your XML file in text only**

You only need to get raw text lines into a buffer for future use.

**Create an image in Java**

You need to use Java API to create some image with background color and draw text on it with the font of your choise.

So far here is a **working example** using Java, not including reading part :

```
String[] aLines = {
    "import ij.IJ;",
    "import ij.ImagePlus;",
    "import ij.gui.Line;",
    "import ij.gui.Roi;",
    "import ij.plugin.PlugIn;",
    "import ij.process.ImageProcessor;",
    "import java.awt.Container;",
    "import java.awt.FlowLayout;",
    "import java.awt.BorderLayout;",
    "import java.awt.event.ActionListener;",
    "import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;",
    "import javax.swing.JDialog;",
    "import javax.swing.JPanel;",
    "import javax.swing.JLabel;",
    "import javax.swing.JButton;",
};

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(80,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

g2d.setColor( Color.WHITE );
g2d.fillRect(0,0,img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());

g2d.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
g2d.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,6));
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

int nCharactersHorizontal = img.getWidth() / fm.charWidth('a') - 1;
int nCharactersVertical = img.getHeight() / 6 - 1;
int x = 2;
int y = 0;

for(String sLine : aLines)
{
    y += 6;

    g2d.drawString(sLine.substring(0,Math.min(sLine.length(),nCharactersHorizontal)),x,y);
}


g2d.dispose();

try
{
    ImageIO.write(img,"png",new File("path/to/your/file.png"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```